# Pass headers in JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, cloudflare-workers

I have a try… catch statement in my code and when there is a catch I want to send a message to me for debugging. Unfortunately I am having a bit of trouble getting headers into the message. Currently I have the following code as the body of my request to the API:

```
body : `Cloudflare:
      ${JSON.stringify(request.cf, null, 2)}
      Headers:
      ${JSON.stringify(request.headers)}
      Error:
      ${err}`
```

The cloudflare and error info comes through perfectly fine, but the headers come out as {} is there any why to fix this?
Thanks!

Edit:
If I remove the `JSON.stringify` from the `request.headers` I get the output `[object Headers]`.

The output currently is:

```
Cloudflare:
{JSON string with lots data}
Headers:
{}
Error:
ReferenceError:…
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do. What body is this? Why don't you stringify the full object but mix it with sting iterpolation?

Comment: Well, what kind of object exactly is `request` and `request.headers`…?

Comment: The body is for an API request, and the string interpolation is being used, but I cannot get the data out of the headers variable.

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the question to include the exact string that is generated after the `body :` property name. And also what it needs to be. Also try `console.table(request.headers)` and show that to us.

Comment: `request` is a variable with info about the request, and `request.headers` includes the headers. If I `console.log(request.headers)` then I get:
HeadersList(44) [
  'accept',
  'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  …
]

Comment: If `HeadersList` is your stuff, you could consider extending it with [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior)

Comment: What kind of object is `HeadersList` exactly…? It's not a standard JavaScript object as far as we can tell.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
const headers = new Headers({
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "authorization": "Basic <auth>"
});
JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries([...headers]));
```

It will print something like this:

```
{"authorization":"Basic <auth>","content-type":"application/json"}
```

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify([...request.headers])`

Explained here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/logging-headers